# Windows scheduler unable to send command to putty

Tags: windows, vbscript, scheduler, putty

I am logging into the server as Administrator to winserver2008.

I created a script called: vbscript.vbs

The purpose of this script is to auto login to linux via putty, then perform command line task.

```
Dim  Shell
Set Shell   = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

output = Shell.Run("C:\putty.exe 1.2.3.4 9321")
wscript.sleep(500)

Shell.Sendkeys "root" & VBCrLf
wscript.sleep(30)

Shell.Sendkeys "password"  & VBCrLf
wscript.sleep(30)
```

When I manually click on vbscript.vbs to execute it, vbscript will fill in root and password to putty.

When I use windows scheduler call to vbscript.vbs to execute it, vbscript won't fill in root and password to putty.

I suspect some permission issue.
I already set putty.exe to run as administrator, allow administrator, administrators group permission for it, but still fail to work when call via windows scheduler.

=====

I just tried with the second scenario, send 2 to the windows calculator, fail too..

testcalc.vbs

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "Calc.exe"
objShell.AppActivate "Calculator"
objShell.SendKeys "2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give up on trying to get `SendKeys` to work from a scheduled task, it's not going to happen. Instead simply pass the login and password on the command line:

```
output = Shell.Run("C:\putty.exe -l root -pw password 1.2.3.4 9321")
```

Alternatively do it with a session file and use `-load`.

If you are then going to execute commands over this connection then I believe you actually want `plink` rather than `putty`.